# Java Ilegal Start of expression

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, compilation

Hello everyone please go easy on me I'm very new to JAVA and am trying to build a program that can display a certain message, but my compiler is saying an error ilegal  start type of expression this is my first software but idk how to fix it and am desperate for help, thanks in advance

```
public class CORE{
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            private String nombre;
            private int edad ;
            private String nacionalidad ;
            CORE (String n) {
                
            nombre = n ;
            } 
    CORE (String n , int e) {
    nombre = n ;
    edad = e ;
    } 
    // Constructor de tres argumentos (nombre , edad y nacionalidad)
    CORE (String n , int e , String nac) {
    nombre = n ;
    edad = e ;
    nacionalidad = nac ;
    } 
    // Metodo para establecer(set) el atributo ”nombre”
    public void estableceNombre (String n) {
    nombre = n ;
    } 
    // Metodo para obtener (get) el atributo ”nombre”
    public String obtenNombre ( ) {
    return nombre ;
    } 
    // Metodo para establecer (set) el atributo ”edad”
    public void estableceEdad (int e) {
    edad = e;
    }
    // Metodo para obtener (get) el atributo ”edad”
    public int obtenEdad ( ) { 
    return edad ;
    }
    // Metodo para establecer (set) el atributo ”nacionalidad ”
    public void estableceNacionalidad (String n) {
    nacionalidad = n ;
    }
    // Metodo para obtener (get) el atributo ” nacionalidad ”
    public String obtenNacionalidad ( ) {
    return nacionalidad ;
    }
    // Metodo para imprimir un mensaje en la salida estándar
    public void mensaje ( ) {
    System.out .println ("Puedo hablar , mi nombre es "+ obtenNombre ( ) ) ;
    }
    // Metodo que simula la accion de comer por parte de una persona
    public void comer ( ) {
    System.out.println ("Mmmmmm uno de los placeres de la vida . . . ") ;
    }      
        }
```

Comment: Remove the line `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you go through the first few sections of [Oracle's Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) that explain how to write well-formed Java programs.

As to your code, your field and method declarations have been nested inside the static main method. It won't compile, this will:

```
public class CORE {
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private String nacionalidad;
    CORE(String n) {

        nombre = n;
    }
    CORE(String n, int e){
        nombre = n;
        edad = e;
    }
    // Constructor de tres argumentos (nombre , edad y nacionalidad)
    CORE(String n, int e, String nac){
        nombre = n;
        edad = e;
        nacionalidad = nac;
    }
    // Metodo para establecer(set) el atributo ”nombre”
    public void estableceNombre (String n){
        nombre = n;
    }
    // Metodo para obtener (get) el atributo ”nombre”
    public String obtenNombre () {
        return nombre;
    }
    // Metodo para establecer (set) el atributo ”edad”
    public void estableceEdad ( int e){
        edad = e;
    }
    // Metodo para obtener (get) el atributo ”edad”
    public int obtenEdad () {
        return edad;
    }
    // Metodo para establecer (set) el atributo ”nacionalidad ”
    public void estableceNacionalidad (String n){
        nacionalidad = n;
    }
    // Metodo para obtener (get) el atributo ” nacionalidad ”
    public String obtenNacionalidad () {
        return nacionalidad;
    }
    // Metodo para imprimir un mensaje en la salida estándar
    public void mensaje () {
        System.out.println("Puedo hablar , mi nombre es " + obtenNombre());
    }
    // Metodo que simula la accion de comer por parte de una persona
    public void comer () {
        System.out.println("Mmmmmm uno de los placeres de la vida . . . ");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this was very helpful, I just started to learn the language, thanks a lot